# How to sort multidimensional array on datetime in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am developing application where in `jquery` I have `multidimensional array` which I have to sort it but `sort on datetime`. Please refer below array which I have to sort.

```
array[["test1.jpg", "abc", "http://localhost7", "2015-09-20T16:23:18.000Z"], ["test2.jpg", "xyz", "http://localhost4", "2015-09-21T11:12:39.000Z"], ["test3.jpg", "pqr", "http://localhost6", "2015-09-20T23:08:42.000Z"]]
```

Any body have a experience and `solutions` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to do this. You can do this using vanilla JS.

```js
var arr = [["test1.jpg", "abc", "http://localhost7", "2015-09-20T16:23:18.000Z"], ["test2.jpg", "xyz", "http://localhost4", "2015-09-21T11:12:39.000Z"], ["test3.jpg", "pqr", "http://localhost6", "2015-09-20T23:08:42.000Z"]];

// Sorting function
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var dt1 = Date.parse(a[3]);
    var dt2 = Date.parse(b[3]);
    
    if (dt1 < dt2) return -1;
    if (dt2 < dt1) return 1;
    return 0;
});

// Output for example:
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    $("<p></p>").text(arr[i][3] + " - " + arr[i][0]).appendTo("body");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.. helpful it

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a[3] > b[3]) return 1;
    if (a[3] < b[3]) return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

The result: http://jsbin.com/bakowowaku/edit?html,js,output